# Android keyboard with different principle?

Tags: keyboard, touchscreen

Android keyboard with different principle?

Hello, I don't know about you but I am still frustrated by typing on a capacitive screen keyboards and I have tried many of them on different phones. Maybe it's because I remember how it was previously on soft resistive screens on phones like Samsung Omnia II where you had to press a bit and it was simply much more precise because it didn't detect just any random part of my huge finger touching the screen, but the point of the pressure instead, which resulted in far less typos.

Of course resistive screens didn't allow multitouch, but the precision was much better IMHO exactly because pressure was a factor. I remember some years ago there was new feature announced allowing the phone to measure touch pressure, but I wonder why wasn't this used exactly for keyboard...or was it?

Another mechanic of typing on today's phone screen is that the position where I LIFT the finger  matters and not position where it first touches and I am actually not sure why is it this way. Are there any keyboards where this would be different and the first touch position would be taken? Or maybe it would be even better to calculate middle point between touch start and touch end to decrease frequency of typos?

Comment: Just making sure you are aware of swipe/Swype based keyboards where your finger moves from letter to letter, i.e. [Gboard slide](https://support.google.com/gboard/answer/2811346)

Comment: I know about these and yes that's a partial solution to this problem

Comment: So it is up the custom keyboard app developer what will be the behavior of the custom keyboard. Since phones were smaller, soft keyboards typically pop-up the letter so it can be seen over the fingertip and by having the app only accept when release allows for mistakes to be corrected (try to hit 'g', see the 'f' key, move until 'g' key, release). Question may fit better at [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) but searching on the Play Store bring up a few soft kbds with larger sizes. If looking for resistive screen device look for 'rugged Android phone'.

Comment: I have "debug touches" in developer options on so I can see that my typos seem to be happening mostly because I touch the right spot, but when releasing my finger it "moves" to a wrong spot. For example very often I tap space, but when releasing finger the last touching spot is on the "n" key, so very often I end up having n characters instead of spaces :-] Seems like there is no such keyboard which would allow this behavior to be changed, yet...